Why do I need to specify the types of the Map.Entry. Is it because the types of the keys are different?
The following code results in the error:

Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

public static Optional<String> getAuthorWithMostPublishedBooks(){
    return books.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Book::getAuthor, Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue).thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getKey).reversed()))
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey);
}

This version compiles successfully:
public static Optional<String> getAuthorWithMostPublishedBooks(){
    return books.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Book::getAuthor, Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry<String, Long>::getValue).thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry<String, Long>::getKey).reversed()))
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey);
}

Is the issue due to different types of the Comparator's keys?
The method should return the author with the most published books in the list. If there's a tie, the first author in alphabetical order must be selected.

I'm not sure if it depends on the Java version, but in some cases Java has problems with inferring the generic type across method chains or nesting of method calls. In that case specifying the generic type explicitly is needed. This seems to be one of those cases.

Note: if reversed() is removed, no need to specify the type of the 2nd Entry; if, additionally one comparing is removed, no type need to be specified  (Java can kind of infer one level...)
